# JDatePicker and properties not working

Tags: java, swing

```
UtilDateModel dateModel = new UtilDateModel();
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(dateModel, p);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, p);
```

I don't know why this is not working, it shows some sort of an error on the p.put, but it doesn't explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Show the error, please.

Comment: Shows a bunch of syntax errors on p.put() (every line that contains it), for example: "," expected, ";" expected, although these lines of code are from another stackoverflow thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create a another class that extends from ***AbstractFormatter***.

Like this

```
public class LabelDateFormatter  extends AbstractFormatter {
    private String datePatern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatern);

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if (value != null) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
            return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

And try this:

`JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new LabelDateFormatter());`

I think this solve your code.